# Rails Devise: Use a Page model or use UserController#action?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am new to Devise.

on

https://rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/master/ActionDispatch/Routing/Mapper

there's an example

```
authenticate :user, lambda {|u| u.role == "admin"} do
  root to: "admin/dashboard#show", as: :user_root
end
```

It is using a "Dashboard" Page-class as model.

Another example would be a "Profile"-Page model.

Isn't it generally sufficient to use the `User#actions` like `User#index` as "Dashboard" and `User#show` as "Profile."

I only think a StaticPage-class for the "Home"-page would be reasonable.

Do you use models like "Dashboard" ?

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

What makes a "Home"-page different from a "Dashboard"-page to you? I think it is reasonable to use a "Dashboard"-page in this case. For me the `users#index` would be to list all users and the `users#show` would be to show the user details and not specific a dashboard. But in the end it's all about your own preferences.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. You're right. The `#index` action is actually to show all users. But then I would use not just a DashboardsController class but also a Dashboard-model so I can compose the Dashboard page via different Associations. Right?

Comment: If you feel the need for a dashboard model to compose the dashboard page than go for it. You could also create a service object for it.